# How should a Mock function accept pipeline input in Pester?

Tags: powershell, pester

I am very new to Pester and I am trying to build tests for a very small and simple function in PowerShell:

```
function Toggle-Notepad {
    if (-not ( Get-Process notepad -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ) )
    {
        Start-Process -FilePath Notepad
    }
    else
    {
        get-process notepad | stop-process
    }

}
```

This function just starts notepad if it is not running, else if it is running it stops it.

The test that I have designed is this:

```
$here = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$sut = (Split-Path -Leaf $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) -replace '\.Tests\.', '.'
. "$here\$sut"

Describe "Toggle-Notepad" {
    Mock Stop-Process { "Process object passed! Stopping notepad!" }
    Mock Start-Process { "Notepad is not running,starting it!" } -ParameterFilter { $Filepath -eq "Notepad" }

    It "Starts notepad if it is not running" {
        Toggle-Notepad | Should be "Notepad is not running,starting it!"
    }

    It "Stops notepad if it is running" {
        Toggle-Notepad | Should be "Process object passed ! Stopping notepad!"
    }
}
```

The above tests run as expected.

How do I rewrite the `Stop-Process` function so that I can specify that this version is for accepting pipeline input?

I tried this, but it is not working:

```
$here = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$sut = (Split-Path -Leaf $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) -replace '\.Tests\.', '.'
. "$here\$sut"

Describe "Toggle-Notepad" {
    Mock stop-process { "Process object passed ! Stopping notepad" } -ParameterFilter { $InputObject -is "System.Diagnostics.Process" }
    Mock Start-Process {"Notepad is not running,starting it!"} -ParameterFilter { $Filepath -eq "Notepad" }

    It "Starts notepad if it is not running" {
        Toggle-Notepad | Should be "Notepad is not running,starting it!"
    }

    It "Stops notepad if it is running" {
        Toggle-Notepad | Should be "Process object passed ! Stopping notepad!"
    }
}
```

Since the `Stop-Process` function is accepting pipeline input my objective is to Mock the function similar to that, not create a general `Stop-Process` function which accepts no params.

Is there any Pester expert out there who can help?

Answer (score 2):

You typically shouldn't need to manually define parameters within a `Mock` because the parameters of the function being mocked are created within the Mock automatically.

The reason your `Stop-Process` Mock isn't working is because you have defined it with the `-ParameterFilter` property which results in it only being called when the defined Parameter is true. Your filter is not working because you are referencing the object type as a string (`"System.Diagnostics.Process"`) rather than as a type (which are declared with square brackets).

The correct code for the Mock is:

```
Mock stop-process { "Process object passed ! Stopping notepad!" } -ParameterFilter { $InputObject -is [System.Diagnostics.Process[]] }
```

I [asked this question of the Pester development team directly](https://github.com/pester/Pester/issues/772) and they suggested a simpler solution of just `-ParameterFilter { $InputObject }` as it will be null if it's not populated with a valid object of that type.

Here's a complete example:

```
Describe 'Mocking stop-process' {

    Mock Stop-Process { 
        Write-Host "Mock stopping: $InputObject"
    } -ParameterFilter { $InputObject }

    It 'Should mock stopping the notepad process' {
        Get-Process notepad | Stop-Process | Should Be $null
    }

}
```

Also FYI, since Pester 3.4.4 there is now a [New-MockObject](https://github.com/pester/Pester/wiki/New-MockObject) command that allows you to create fake objects of any type:

> New-MockObject is a Pester function (introduced in Pester 3.4.4) that
>   allows you to create "fake" objects of almost any type to run in
>   Pester mocks. These "fake objects" allow your mocks to return the same
>   type as the function it was mocking to pass the result to entities
>   that are strongly typed.

It's not necessary in your scenario but I thought you might find it relevant/interesting.

Comment: Saying _"shouldn't define paraemters [...]"_ doesn't make the other answer _incorrect_, especially if it works like expected.

Comment: Yeah actually on reflection you could define additional parameters that weren't present in the function of cmdlet being mocked I guess, but you should be careful not to redefine parameters that are created automatically. Sorry, i'll revise my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock a function accepting pipeline values like any other function:

```
Describe "Toggle-Notepad" {
    Mock Stop-Process {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param(
            [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
            $InputObject
        )
        return "Process object passed! Stopping notepad"
    } -ParameterFilter { $InputObject -is "System.Diagnostics.Process" }

    Mock Start-Process {
        return "Notepad is not running, starting it!"
    } -ParameterFilter { $Filepath -eq "Notepad" }

    It "Starts notepad if it is not running" {
        Toggle-Notepad | Should be "Notepad is not running, starting it!"
    }

    It "Stops notepad if it is running" {
        Toggle-Notepad | Should be "Process object passed! Stopping notepad!"
    }
}
```

Please note also that your mocked `Stop-Process` has typos in it so it won't work.